# How to add multiple local repositories at once into SourceTree Windows version?

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I have a folder in which I have a couple of dozens of sub-folders, each with it's own project versioned with git, something like this:

- projects:

  - project_a
  - project_b
  - ...
  - project_z

I would like to add them all in a SourceTree in some folder.

In OSX version there is a way to do that, but I cannot find how to do it in Windows version (I have version 3.1.2 installed if it matters).

Do anybody know how to add all repositories from a given folder into SourceTree at once?

Answer (score -1):

You can select all the folders and just drag them into the Local Repos tab in a New Tab. It should just add all of the repos